# passing selected checkbox values to next/new screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a checkbox widget where I'd like to pass only selected values of the checkboxes to a new screen , I'd like for the values to only be passed only once a checkbox has been pressed . below is the code for the checkbox widget :

```
class _CheckBoxPageState extends ConsumerState<CheckBoxPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final readAsync = ref.watch(checkRepoProvider);
    final model = ref.watch(checkboxProvider);

    bool check1 = false;
    bool check2 = false;

    String? saveFirstValue;
    String? saveSecondValue;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("check"),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 24, 24),
          child: MaterialButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: ()  {
              if (saveFirstValue!.isNotEmpty && saveSecondValue!.isNotEmpty) {
                String bothValues = "$saveFirstValue $saveSecondValue";
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            DisplayPage(bothValues: bothValues)));
              } else {
                if (saveFirstValue!.isNotEmpty) {
                  String saveCheck = "$saveFirstValue";
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DisplayPage(
                                saveCheck: saveCheck,
                              )));
                } else if (saveSecondValue!.isNotEmpty) {
                  String saveCheck2 = "$saveSecondValue";
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DisplayPage(
                                saveCheck2: saveCheck2,
                              )));
                }
              }
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Add meal",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 245, 245)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: readAsync.when(
            data: (check) => ListView(
                children: check
                    .map(
                      (e) => Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(e.checkbox1),
                            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                            value: check1,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              check1 = value!;
                              saveFirstValue = e.checkbox1;
                            },
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          ),
                          CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(e.checkbox2),
                            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                            value: check2,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              check2 = value!;
                              saveSecondValue = e.checkbox2;
                            },
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList()),
            error: (e, s) => Center(
                  child: Text("$e"),
                ),
```

below is where i'd like for the values to be passed once they've been selected:

```
class DisplayPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const DisplayPage({
    Key? key,
    this.bothValues,
    this.saveCheck,
    this.saveCheck2,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? saveCheck;
  final String? saveCheck2;
  final String? bothValues;
  static const String route = "/display";

  @override
  ConsumerState<DisplayPage> createState() => _DisplayPageState();
}

class _DisplayPageState extends ConsumerState<DisplayPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("display"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(widget.saveCheck!),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a list to add/remove selected check  (if check is true then add or if false remove that value from list )
2. navigate and pass selected list you can get all selected values.